# Separate Execution Queues for a single executor to keep track of remaining

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

In my Jetty service, I have an endpoint which triggers a number of threads to be run. I'm currently using a `ThreadExecutorPool` to execute my `Runnable`s. But I want to be able to know how many jobs are remaining for each individual request to the endpoint and allow for multiple concurrent requests.

My thought is to do something like have a single queue for each request and have some kind of executor which just pulls from each queue in a round robin manner. I'm wondering if something like this exists that works out of the box.

Note that I don't care about execution order. What I do care about is that each request (i.e. session) is given equal time and that, for each session, I can find out how many threads have not yet been started/completed.

So I guess a MultiQueueExecutor or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to be able to know how many jobs are remaining for each individual request to the endpoint and allow for multiple concurrent requests.

I would just use your `Future`s appropriately in combination with a [`ExecutionCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).  If you use an ECS your web requests will be notified as soon as each of the tasks finishes so they will always know how many tasks are left to run.

> What I do care about is that each request (i.e. session) is given equal time and that, for each session, I can find out how many threads have not yet been started/completed.

Well the "equal time" is not guaranteed and there is are race conditions around when the jobs are submitted to the thread-pool given the FIFO nature of it.  Whether or not this solution works depends highly on what you will do with the information in question.

Comment: Roughly equal time. I.e. Request 1 should not block Request 2.
My problem with polling the Futures is that it takes time for tasks to be added to the queue. So, unless I'm missing something, polling futures will simply tell me when tasks complete, but not how many are currently in the queue.

Comment: Each of the requests will then know how many of their tasks have completed and how many are left.   You can also look at the TPE queue to see how many tasks are in the queue overall.  Can you be more specific in terms of your requirements?  @marisbest2

Comment: In terms of equal time, you have a couple of choices.  You can create a cached thread pool which will fork a new thread for every new request.  This might not be good if you are getting a bunch of requests.  Otherwise I'm not sure how a request will start tasks that aren't blocked by previously submitted tasks by other requests unless each request has  it's on TPE but again that might thrash your server @marisbest2.

Comment: The client says something like "Process all items matching my query" and then the server processes those items. First it needs to get those items which takes time. Meanwhile, a second client may have also said "Process all items matching my other query." So I have two InputStreams from the database (one per request) each of which are adding tasks to a single Queue. This makes it impossible to tell how many tasks are from Request 1 and how many from Request 2. My thought is having 2 queues, polled in a round robin, and figure out how many tasks are still in each queue.

Comment: Neither client, nor the server, knows how many tasks will be generated per request. But we can assume that as soon as the Queue for a single request has no more tasks, it will never again have any tasks.